# Using DATEDIFF to ignore negative values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where I need to check the sent date of various email threads against date column in another table and determine version number if email sent date occurs after the date specified in the table. I used datediff() for this but I get negative values. I can't use ABS() because it doesn't make sense here.Is there any way I can get the desired result? A sample of the query I am using is

```
select distinct
  x.OPTENTION_DATE,
  email.ID,
  x.NAME,
  email.SEND_DATE,
  DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE) AS DT_DIFF 
from 
  classification_version x,
  classification_element y,
  email 
where 
  x.id_project = y.ID_PROJECT and 
  x.ID_PROJECT = email.ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT and 
  y.ID_PROJECT = 11 and 
  y.ID_COMPANY=1 
order by 
  email.SEND_DATE ASC
```

The output for this query is

```
OPTENTION_DATE  ID  NAME    SEND_DATE   DT_DIFF
2014-11-05  3   Version 2   2014-01-13 14:09:34     -296
2015-02-18  3   Version 3   2014-01-13 14:09:34     -401
2014-01-09  3   Version 1   2014-01-13 14:09:34     4
2014-11-05  62  Version 2   2015-01-12 18:46:10     68
2015-02-18  62  Version 3   2015-01-12 18:46:10     -37
2014-01-09  62  Version 1   2015-01-12 18:46:10     368
2014-11-05  61  Version 2   2015-01-19 20:50:09     75
2015-02-18  61  Version 3   2015-01-19 20:50:09     -30
2014-01-09  61  Version 1   2015-01-19 20:50:09     375
```

My desired output is for email id 3 version 1 should be selected,for email id 62 version 2 should be selected. If I use ABS() and then MIN() version 3 will be selected which is wrong because the send date is before the actual date.Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: *"The output for this query is"*....

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried formatting but it came out like this.

Comment: OPTENTION_DATE  ID  NAME  SEND_DATE  DT_DIFF
2014-11-05  3  Version 2  2014-01-13 14:09:34  -296
2015-02-18  3  Version 3  2014-01-13 14:09:34  -401
2014-01-09  3  Version 1  2014-01-13 14:09:34  4
2014-11-05  62  Version 2  2015-01-12 18:46:10  68
2015-02-18  62  Version 3  2015-01-12 18:46:10  -37
2014-01-09  62  Version 1  2015-01-12 18:46:10  368
2014-11-05  61  Version 2  2015-01-19 20:50:09  75
2015-02-18  61  Version 3  2015-01-19 20:50:09  -30
2014-01-09  61  Version 1  2015-01-19 20:50:09  375

Comment: I fixed that (needed an open line). By the way, you are (were) using `distinct` wrong. `distinct` is a modifier for the entire select. You cannot 'distinct' one field. Adding parentheses won't change that.

Comment: But if I remove that I get a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Amend your join criteria such that one thing must be greater than or equal to another thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `email.SEND_DATE >  x.OPTENTION_DATE` condition in `WHERE` clause and use `MIN(DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE))` and `GROUP BY ID`. It will find minimum positive value for each id.
Try below query :

```
select x.OPTENTION_DATE,
       email.ID,
       x.NAME,
       email.SEND_DATE,
       MIN(DATEDIFF(email.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE)) AS DT_DIFF 
from 
       classification_version x,
       classification_element y,
       email 
where
    x.id_project = y.ID_PROJECT
and x.ID_PROJECT = email.ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT
and y.ID_PROJECT = 11
and y.ID_COMPANY=1
and email.SEND_DATE > x.OPTENTION_DATE
group by 
    ID
order by 
    email.SEND_DATE ASC
```

Comment: I tried this but x.NAME and x.OPTENTION_DATE are coming up wrong

Comment: can you share output after applying this query?

Comment: 2014-11-05 69 Version 2 2015-02-27 12:40:28 114
2015-02-18 69 Version 3 2015-02-27 12:40:28 9
2014-01-09 69 Version 1 2015-02-27 12:40:28 414

Comment: After query                                                                                                                   '2014-11-05', '69', 'Version 2', '2015-02-27 12:40:28', '9'
But it should be Version 3 as per the above output

Comment: remove `distinct` and try it.

Comment: IF I use group by it's returning wrong values for name and date

Comment: yeah, that's why I told you to try removing `distinct`.

Comment: can you share tables and data on sqlfiddle?

Comment: It looks like sqlfiddle.com is undergoing some changes . Is there any other way I can share the tables?

Comment: I am not able to post it there. It shows a popup something went wrong. When I use group by the result set is wrong

Comment: CREATE TABLE `classification_version` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ID_PROJECT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `OPTENTION_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `NAME` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `classification_element` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_PROJECT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_COMPANY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_VERSION` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_PROJECT` (`ID_PROJECT`),
  KEY `ID_COMPANY` (`ID_COMPANY`),
  KEY `ID_VERSION` (`ID_VERSION`))

Comment: CREATE TABLE `email` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SUBJECT` text,
  `SEND_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ID_SENDER` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ATA` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_SENDER` (`ID_SENDER`),
  KEY `ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT` (`ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT`))

Comment: Add this in your question, not in comments.